# concerning about homology of a graph

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm very lost in the following Bredon problem 9-pag 240

Let $G \subset S^n$ be a finite connected graph. Find $H_{\bullet}(S^n \setminus G)$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know Alexander duality ?

Comment: unfortunately, not sir. However, I could try to look it at.